# NavigationView containing VStack embedded with HStack and List causes error when swiping backwards

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-navigationview

I currently have a navigationView embedded with a navigationLink that leads to a VStack that contains an HStack and a List. For some reason, when I drag back to the previous navigation in the stack and leave it halfway, the app glitches and needs to be restarted. This only occurs if I include the navigationbar title.

Here is the code for the view that is embedded in the navigationView. Removing the HStack causes the code bug to stop. The navigation bar items section is not large enough for my desired behavior.

Desired Behavior: Static HStack with a list below it and navigation bar title.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
struct Sell: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(self.stores) { store in
            NavigationLink(destination: StoreHome2(store: store)) {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text(store.storeName)
               
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sell").foregroundColor(Color.black))
    }.onAppear(perform: getStores)
}
}

import SwiftUI

struct StoreHome2: View {
    var categoryItem: [String: [Item]]
    var store: Store
    @State var isPresentingFirst = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresentingFirst = true
                }) {
                  Image(systemName: "plus")
                }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingFirst) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }.padding()

            List {
                ForEach(categoryItem.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                    Text("Hello World")
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }

        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello World"))
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: *I currently have a navigationView embedded with a navigationLink*. Please provide the code for them as well.

Comment: Can not recreate any issue with the above code

Comment: @pawello2222 added the code

Comment: @davidev, the issue only occurs when the app is downloaded onto a phone and slides back to the previous navigation in the navigation stack, pressing the back button does not cause an issue. When sliding, leave it halfway between the two screens and youll notice the navigation bar title freezes up.

Comment: Tested it with Xcode 11.5 on a real device and couldn't see any issue on back sliding.